# How to replace or delete multiple substring in a string after a specific character using PHP?

Tags: php, string, replace

I have a string like this, what I want is to delete all those 702, 703, 704, 705... at the end of each line:

```
   ftp://Lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit@Lorem-ipsum.com:1155/Lorem-ipsum/[Lorem-ipsum]Lorem-ipsum701 702
   ftp://Lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit@Lorem-ipsum.com:1158/Lorem-ipsum/[Lorem-ipsum]Lorem-ipsum702 703
   ftp://Lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit@Lorem-ipsum.com:3160/Lorem-ipsum/[Lorem-ipsum]Lorem-ipsum703 704
   ftp://Lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit@Lorem-ipsum.com:5070/Lorem-ipsum/[Lorem-ipsum]Lorem-ipsum704 705
   ftp://Lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit@Lorem-ipsum.com:2162/Lorem-ipsum/[Lorem-ipsum]Lorem-ipsum705 706
   ftp://Lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit@Lorem-ipsum.com:2163/Lorem-ipsum/[Lorem-ipsum]Lorem-ipsum706 707
   ftp://Lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit@Lorem-ipsum.com:3169/Lorem-ipsum/[Lorem-ipsum]Lorem-ipsum707 708
   ftp://Lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit@Lorem-ipsum.com:6183/Lorem-ipsum/[Lorem-ipsum]Lorem-ipsum708 709
   ftp://Lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit@Lorem-ipsum.com:1178/Lorem-ipsum/[Lorem-ipsum]Lorem-ipsum709 710
   ftp://Lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit@Lorem-ipsum.com:1000/Lorem-ipsum/[Lorem-ipsum]Lorem-ipsum710 711
   ftp://Lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit@Lorem-ipsum.com:2181/Lorem-ipsum/[Lorem-ipsum]Lorem-ipsum711 712
   ftp://Lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit@Lorem-ipsum.com:4178/Lorem-ipsum/[Lorem-ipsum]Lorem-ipsum712 713
   ftp://Lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit@Lorem-ipsum.com:4279/Lorem-ipsum/[Lorem-ipsum]Lorem-ipsum713 714
   ftp://Lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit@Lorem-ipsum.com:5202/Lorem-ipsum/[Lorem-ipsum]Lorem-ipsum714 715
   ftp://Lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit@Lorem-ipsum.com:4288/Lorem-ipsum/[Lorem-ipsum]Lorem-ipsum715 716
   ftp://Lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit@Lorem-ipsum.com:5220/Lorem-ipsum/[Lorem-ipsum]Lorem-ipsum716 717
   ftp://Lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit@Lorem-ipsum.com:5222/Lorem-ipsum/[Lorem-ipsum]Lorem-ipsum717 718
   ftp://Lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit@Lorem-ipsum.com:2922/Lorem-ipsum/[Lorem-ipsum]Lorem-ipsum718 719
   ftp://Lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit@Lorem-ipsum.com:5225/Lorem-ipsum/[Lorem-ipsum]Lorem-ipsum719 720
   ftp://Lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit@Lorem-ipsum.com:5227/Lorem-ipsum/[Lorem-ipsum]Lorem-ipsum720 721
   ftp://Lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit@Lorem-ipsum.net:1111/Lorem-ipsum/[Lorem-ipsum]Lorem-ipsum721 722
   ftp://Lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit@Lorem-ipsum.net:6278/Lorem-ipsum/[Lorem-ipsum]Lorem-ipsum722 723
   ftp://Lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit@Lorem-ipsum.net:4014/Lorem-ipsum/[Lorem-ipsum]Lorem-ipsum723 724
   ftp://Lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit@Lorem-ipsum.net:4016/Lorem-ipsum/[Lorem-ipsum]Lorem-ipsum724 725
   ftp://Lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit@Lorem-ipsum.net:5018/Lorem-ipsum/[Lorem-ipsum]Lorem-ipsum725 726
   ftp://Lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit@Lorem-ipsum.net:2010/Lorem-ipsum/[Lorem-ipsum]Lorem-ipsum726 727
   ftp://Lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit@Lorem-ipsum.net:2012/Lorem-ipsum/[Lorem-ipsum]Lorem-ipsum727 728
   ftp://Lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit@Lorem-ipsum.net:2012/Lorem-ipsum/[Lorem-ipsum]Lorem-ipsum728 729
   ftp://Lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit@Lorem-ipsum.net:1119/Lorem-ipsum/[Lorem-ipsum]Lorem-ipsum729 730
   ftp://Lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit@Lorem-ipsum.net:5084/Lorem-ipsum/[Lorem-ipsum]Lorem-ipsum730 731
```

Anyone can help me please? I want to use php to solve this, Thanks!

Comment: is this a single string?

Comment: Did you try [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.preg-replace.php)?

Comment: Thank you! It works! This is a single string btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$replacement = preg_replace('/[0-9]{3} [0-9]{3}/', '', $string);
```

It seems to work line-by-line and for the entire string as well.

Comment: $replacement = preg_replace('/\s\d{3}/', '', $string); Thank you, it works. In order to delete last 3 digits after the space, I use this one to make it work.